# A better way than nesting foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I've got a list of Radios that I'm trying to produce a more user-friendly version of.  Behind the scenes all descriptions are stringIds and all part numbers are DB Ids.

Right now, I've got this code:

```
       var z = (from w in wireless
                                         join s in allStrings on w.DescriptionId equals s.StringId
                                         join u in allUids on w.Uid equals u.Uid
                                         where s.LanguageId == 0
                                         select new {w, s, u});

        List<RadioProperty> rp = new List<RadioProperty>();
        foreach (var x in z)
        {
            foreach(var y in x.w.RadioToVoltage)
            {
                rp.Add(new RadioProperty
                {
                    PartNumber = x.u.PartNumber,
                    Description = x.s.Description,
                    CurrentType = y.Id.VoltageType,
                    Voltage = y.Id.VoltageValue,
                });
            }
        }
```

Basically, every radio part number can have several voltage options.
We could have Radio ABC with 48VAC, 110VAC and 240VAC options, so I'm trying to create 3 separate RadioProperty items, one for each voltage option.

Is there a better way of doing this?  I'm running .Net 3.5.

Thanks

Comment: Regardless of your approach, looking at this code for the first time I am more confused by the non-descriptive variable names than the nested loops.

Comment: True, not my normal naming scheme, just trying to throw together an example really quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not tested but you should be able to get it all in one linq statement somethin glike

```
 List<RadioProperty> rp = (from w in wireless
                     join s in allStrings on w.DescriptionId equals s.StringId
                     join u in allUids on w.Uid equals u.Uid
                     where s.LanguageId == 0
                     from t in w.RadioToVoltage
                     select new RadioProperty {
                         PartNumber = w.u.PartNumber,
                         Description = w.s.Description,
                         CurrentType = t.Id.VoltageType,
                         Voltage = t.Id.VoltageValue,
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you.   I knew I was writing ugly code, yours is much better.